# Cannot persist data using kotlin and spring data

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, kotlin, spring-data-jpa

I wanted to take advantage of inheritance in JPA. I have three classes:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(
        name = "MY_DISC",
        discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING
)
open class BaseClass(
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        val id: Long? = null,
        ...shared things
) 

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "FIRST_VALUE")
class FirstClass(...shared) : BaseClass(...shared things ) {

}


@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "SECOND_VALUE")
class SecondClass(...shared) : BaseClass(...shared things ) {

}
```

I have also created repositories:

```
@Repository
interface FirstClassRepo : CrudRepository<FirstClass, Long> {
}
... other similar
```

However, whenever I am trying to save FirstClass using save on the repository I get:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The column index is out of range: 4, number of columns: 3.
```

I have already checked a lot of links, however none of them were working, is there any tutorial for kotlin + spring data jpa + inheritance? Or am I missing something in that solution?

Comment: Are you creating tables manually or is it created by jpa?

Comment: It is created by jpa. The only thing that I have specified is: spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create

Comment: Can you add this to `application.properties` and update the question with generated sql for `FirstClass` table creation and `save`? `spring.jpa.show-sql=true` and `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true`

Comment: Actually if you remove `@DiscriminatorColumn` and `@DiscriminatorValue` annotations it should work

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the only thing that was working, was adding a field with the annotation

```
@Column("MY_DESC", insertable = false, updatable = false)
```

It solves all of my concerns.